# Reason ForceType application/x-httpd-php on .htaccess not working at all

Tags: php, .htaccess, mime-types

I have tried to use:

.htaccess

```
<Files client>
 ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

client file

```
<?php 
     echo "FOO BAR";
?>
```

Just to test, but the server is not parsing the client file, it just serves it up as a file download. I tried SetHandler also without luck.

**UPDATE**

I'm using MediaTemple and the have there own way of doing things. 
I can't use ForceType bu I can use this.

```
<Files client>
     SetHandler php-script
</Files client>
```

Comment: This question makes little sense without telling us what server you're on :P

Comment: I'm on Media Temple servers, the gs Grid they run Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MediaTemple and the have there own way of doing things. I can't use ForceType bu I can use this.

SetHandler php-script

Answer (score 2):

ForceType requires AllowOverride of FileInfo

check your httpd.conf if this is set.

Comment: Hmm.. Im on shared host so can't do that altought my host claims I can use ForceType.

Answer (score 0):

```
#suPHP_ConfigPath /home4/nitrousg/public_html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddType text/html .html
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

How do Upgrade to 7 and above servers?

Tech said my force type does not work for the upgrade??

```
<Files Forged-Wheels>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files Wheels>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but page us still not pulling up images.  Blank Page.